# COM: How to get all running objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

You know GetActiveObject just can get the COM object of the first opened application. How to get all running objects? e.g. I run two Excel applications, How to get the two Excel objects in C++ code?

Comment: ¤ See [the Microsoft KB article 180885](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190985) "How to get IDispatch of an Excel or Word document from an OCX". This KB article is cited as the answer to your question by an article that explains [why you can't get at the application instances directly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238975). I found these in a second or two of googling. Typing it up here, with the freaking laptop keyboard acting like it's alive and even closing the Firefox tab, took several orders of magnitude longer. I hate the current laptop designs, with mousepads. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I had read these two article. But the way still can't resolve my broblem. So, if the two Excels open one same document, We only can get the first one, that's a problem. Any other solutions? thanks.

Comment: This is by design, there really is only one instance of Excel running.  Easy to see with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  Use the Workbooks object to iterate the open documents.

Comment: perharps the excel example is not exactly. I meant the similar application， run it twice， there are two instances in taskmgr. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually only one instance of Excel as Hans says. If there is only one instance it will refuse to open the same document twice.

But there may be more than one, typically if a second has been started explicitly. In that case it may open the same file (though you will get a warning about locking).

They may or may not both appear in the Running Object Table. Use ROT viewer or something like this to determine whether that is the case:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/ccccc9bd-f21a-4f74-a3f0-64a594fa1b16

Finally you might consider using Microsoft UI Automation:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294(VS.85).aspx